# How to split Excel table into multiple pages Word file

Tags: excel, ms-word

I'm attempting to split Excel table into multiple pages Word file, each row in the Excel table composed of Title, Authors and Abstract which I try to transpose into Title, Subtitle and Paragraph, respectively, in Word file. I am using the following code but for some reason it's only duplicate the first line in my table over and over again to all pages.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73iTY.png)

```
Program <- RTF("rtf.doc")

for(i in df$Title) {
addHeader(Program, title = df$Title,subtitle= df$Authors)
addParagraph(Program, df$abstract)
addPageBreak(Program)
done(Program)}
```

Comment: So why not use mailmerge?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the problem and here is the correct version of the code:

```html
Program <- RTF("program.doc")
Title <- df$Title
Authors<- df$Authors
Abstract<- df$abstract

for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
addHeader(Program, title = Title[i], subtitle = Authors[i])
addParagraph(Program, Abstract[i])
addPageBreak(Program)
done(Program)
}
```